# Is it possible to acquire different IP addresses if I already have one IP address?

Tags: proxy, ip, squid

What I want to ask is whether its possible to create multiple IP adresses from one server with a single IP. I would like to use them with a Squid proxy.

For example I have the IP address `34.123.321.123`. Using Squid I would like to also run proxies with the IP `34.123.321.124` or `34.123.321.22`.

Do I have to buy that IP or can I somehow get it from the main(`34.123.321.123`) IUP?

Comment: Well, this is not really a Squid proxy question as much as this is an IP address issue. And IP addresses are assigned (in ranges) to ISPs and hosting providers. So you can’t just “get” one because you decided you want one. You need to somehow acquire the other addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that with public IP addresses you don't control. You can only use the public IP address(es) that you have been assigned by your ISP, otherwise there will be no way to route the traffic from the rest of the internet to your machine. If you ordered a block of IP addresses from your ISP (which requires a bit of work these days) then you can assign all of them to one device, or split them up between devices (this would be handled by your router).